# Content background image not showing in body

Tags: css, background-image

I have a background image in the main div (.cont) which is not showing at full width and just cannot figure out how to make it visible in 2nd row of divs (.mainl and .mainr). The page is at http://sallymilo.com/0test/

Can you please advise me on the fix:

The CSS:

```
.cont { width:100%; max-width:1000px; margin:auto; background-image:url('https://myimagefiles.com/datasales/bg.png'); }
.hdrl { width:33%; height:131px; float:left; position:relative; background-image:url('https://myimagefiles.com/datasales/hdrl.png'); background-position: center center; background-repeat: no-repeat; }
.hdrr { width:67%; height:131px; float:left; position:relative; background-image:url('https://myimagefiles.com/datasales/hdrr.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; }
.ttl { position:relative; float:left; z-index:10; margin:2em 1em 0 1em; color:#fff; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, san-serif; font-size:24px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center; }
.mainl { width:65%; float:left; position:relative; }
.mainr { width:35%; float:left; position:relative; }
.desc { color:#00356f; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, san-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; text-align:left; margin:0 2em 0 2em; }
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="cont">
  <div class="hdrl"></div>
  <div class="hdrr"> 
<div class="ttl">[[Title]] of up to 80 characters will go into this area - right in this space!!!</div>
 </div>
<div style="clear: both"></div>
  <div class="mainl"> 
    <p class="desc"><br>
      [[Description]]</p>
  <p>tabs</p>
    <p align="center"><img src="thanks.png"  style="max-width:209px;"></p>
</div>
  <div class="mainr"> 
    <p align="center">[[Picture1]]</p>
    <p align="center">[[Picture2]]</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `clear:both` is causing your break in the image background.

Add your `clear` to the bottom, just after your `mainr` div. The background will then extend into `mainl` and `mainr` area.

The reason your header is not full width, is because you are applying a `max-width` attribute, which will only allow a maximum width. `1000px` in your case.

Take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/bqboyLmb/